# Appium 2 Webdriverio XCUITest - How to approve permissions modal iOS

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, xcuitest

I'm completely stuck on allowing permissions on iOS in automation testing with Appium 2. I want to proceed with permissions and click `Allow`. But nothing happens, find element gets 3 retry and then timeout. ┐(´•_•`)┌

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkDie.png)

- I'm able to install and launch app on real device.
- I can find element by accessibility id "Allow" when searching with **Appium inspector** and even send action tap.

my setup:

- Appium: 2.0.0-beta.55

```
const wdio = require("webdriverio");

 const optsLocalIOS = {
    path: '/wd/hub/',
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        platformName: "ios",
        "appium:app": "/my/correct/path",
        "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
        'appium:autoAcceptAlerts': 'true',
        "appium:xcodeOrgId": "myteamid",
        "appium:xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",
        "appium:udid":"auto",
        "appium:showXcodeLog": true
    }
};

async function main () {
    const driver = await wdio.remote(optsLocalIOS);

    // accessibility id not working
    const element = await driver.$(`~Allow`) 

    // xpath id not working
    const element = await driver.$(`//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Allow"]`)
   
    // click not working
    await element.click()

    // tap not working
    await driver.touchAction({
         action: 'tap',
         element: element
     });

    // await driver.deleteSession();
    // when attaching to session from appium inspector, the button is there
}

main();
```

In logs is just timeout

```
2023-02-27T16:47:38.616Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'xpath', value: '//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Allow"]' }
2023-02-27T16:49:38.626Z WARN webdriver: Request timed out! Consider increasing the "connectionRetryTimeout" option.
```

[image]

Any tips & tricks are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**for iOS 15:**

Webdriverio has the method `driver.acceptAlert()`. And that's it.

**for iOS 16:**

```
await driver.executeScript("mobile: alert", [{action: "accept"}]);
```

Don't forget to check your Appium version - use Appium 2.